# Odoo inherit error when try to use mail_thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-12

I am trying to make a notification app in odoo which will send mail to the user. I have found documentation https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/mixins.html, but when I trying to start odoo I receive error non-existing model 'mail.thread'. How can I resolve this problem?

**models.py:**

```
class skype_bot(models.Model):
    _name = 'my.skype'
    _inherit = ['mail.thread']
    _description = 'My Skype'

    # class MySkype(skpy.SkypeEventLoop):
    #     def onEvent(self, event):
    #         if isinstance(event, skpy.SkypeNewMessageEvent):
    #             print(repr(event))
    #             message = ('New message from user {} at {}: \'{} \''.format(event.msg.userId,
    #                                                                         event.msg.time.strftime(
    #                                                                             '%H:%M dd. %d.%m.%Y'),
    #                                                                         event.msg.content))

    @api.one
    def SentMail(self, message):
        print('called function sentmail')
        self.env['mail.message'].create({'message_type': 'notification',
                                         'subtype': self.env.ref('mail.mt_comment').id, 
                                         'body': message,
                                         'subject': 'Message subject',
                                         'needaction_partner_ids': [(4, 3)],

                                         })


        self.message_post(
            subject='Skype message',
            body=message,
            partner_ids=[(4, 3)]
        )
```

**log**

> сту 19 16:20:46 PK odoo[20993]:   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 417, in load_modules
>       сту 19 16:20:46 PK odoo[20993]:     force, status, report, loaded_modules, update_module, models_to_check)
>       сту 19 16:20:46 PK odoo[20993]:   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 313, in load_marked_modules
>       сту 19 16:20:46 PK odoo[20993]:     perform_checks=perform_checks, models_to_check=models_to_check
>       сту 19 16:20:46 PK odoo[20993]:   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 188, in load_module_graph
>       сту 19 16:20:46 PK odoo[20993]:     model_names = registry.load(cr, package)
>       сту 19 16:20:46 PK odoo[20993]:   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 240, in load
>       сту 19 16:20:46 PK odoo[20993]:     model = cls._build_model(self, cr)
>       сту 19 16:20:46 PK odoo[20993]:   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 458, in _build_model
>       сту 19 16:20:46 PK odoo[20993]:     raise TypeError("Model %r inherits from non-existing model %r." % (name, parent))
>       сту 19 16:20:46 PK odoo[20993]: TypeError: Model 'my.skype' inherits from non-existing model 'mail.thread'. - - -

Comment: Do you have `mail` addon in your addon's dependencies (`depends` key in `__manifest__.py`)?

Comment: @Naglis please write an answer. Maybe it's worth to write more about, why that dependency is needed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to add in your module, at the ****manifest**.py**, the following dependency:
 **'depends'    : ['mail'],**
Because you are trying to inherit from 'mail' module from addons (mail.thread is found on this module). Basic this module it is not installed. So you are trying to inherit from a non-existing model until you install this module. I recomand you to use depends on all modules that are using another models (inherit model/views). In that case, you will no longer get any errors like this.
Good luck!